# Move files between commits

Tags: git, git-commit

I have two consequential commits, somewhere in the local history, and one file was mistakenly added into the second. I want to fix the situation.

I do not understand how should I use the interactive rebase. I did `git rebase -i HEAD~10` and choosen to edit the commit with file in order to check it out from there. I use git guit but, see no files in the commit area. I can choose to amend the previous commit then I see the files. But, I cannot add the misplaced file to that previous commit since I do not see the file in the current commit to start with.

Comment: Keep in mind that changing any past commit rewrites the history and you're getting completely new hashes since that commit. Don't do that if the commit is already published.

Comment: @aragaer I have intentionally stipulated that I rewrite the _LOCAL_ history.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If I don't get it wrong, what you want is move some change that was included commit 2 to commit 1.

I find the easiest way to do that is doing two consecutive interactive rebases.

In the first one, you split commit 2 into two commits: the first including just the change you want to move, and the second including all the rest. We have now commits 1, 2.1, and 2.2.

Then you rebase again, and this time choose to squash commit 2.1 into 1.

Answer (score 42):

So, when rebasing, choose to edit both the commit where you added the file by mistake, and the one you want to add it to in that order.  If the file is in a later commit, but should be in an earlier one, you will have to reorder the lines.  For example, I start with

```
pick 8de731b Commit with missing file.
pick bbef925 Commit with too many files.
pick 52490ce More history.
```

I need to change it to

```
edit bbef925 Commit with too many files.
edit 8de731b Commit with missing file.
pick 52490ce More history.
```

Then,

```
# In the commit containing an extra file
git reset HEAD^ badfile.c
git commit --amend
git rebase --continue

# Now in the commit to add it to
git add badfile.c
git commit --amend
git rebase --continue
```

Unfortunately, when editing history in one branch, I don't know of any way to avoid editing history in all branches.  Rebasing should be done as early as possible to avoid problems like this.  In my simple case here, I can merge master and the other branch, but the commits don't merge, then I have to rebase in master, and reorder and squash the commits, like this:

```
pick 7cd915f Commit with missing file.
fixup 8de731b Commit with missing file. #This was the higher of the two entries
pick 8b92c5a Commit with too many files.
fixup bbef925 Commit with too many files. #This was the higher of the two entries
pick 94c3f7f More history.
fixup 52490ce More history. #This was the higher of the two entries
```

**Late edit:** I just noticed I was accidentally reordering the commit history as a carryover from my original answer.  Swapping the lines in the rebase changes the order you commit; after editing, you can rebase again and swap them back to go back to the original commit order.

Comment: The badfile was added later rather than too early. Do you say that I should create a new branch at the point of history?

Comment: I have managed to move the file in the new branch, which had second commit at the top. But, I have a problem now rebasing the whole history on the top of this branch. It seems that two commits of the main conflict with the two commits of the new branch.

Comment: I've updated the answer, but unfortunately the only way I know to fix this is to edit history in all branches, in one way or another.

Comment: +1, except that I'm not sure that the `--amend` switch is a good idea: it seemed to bring in stuff that I didn't want.

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you! I'd also like to point out that this also works when moving files across branches, because the reset file(s) remain in the staging area when the rebase is complete.

Comment: what does the `git reset HEAD^ badfile.c` will do here?

Comment: okay. I understand the `reset HEAD^` working here. The changes in `badfile.c` will be replaced with the previous changes (from parent commit). In my case `git rebase --continue` was failing with error `badfile.c: needs update` `You must edit all merge conflicts and then mark them as resolved using git add`. so I committed `badfile.c` again. and after this round of rebasing I needed to rebase again where I squashed this new commit in the other commit.

Comment: @MohammadFaisal I had the same. I just did `git stash` before `git rebase continue` and then when editing next commit `git stash pop` and `git add bad file`, and then `git commit --amend` and `git rebase --continue`

Answer (score 11):

As I often stumble upon this issue, I wrote a script for this. It works fully automatically. You can find it on [Github](https://github.com/MikhailGolubtsov/git-mv-changes). Copy it to the local filesystem, add it to PATH and you'll be able to run it as:

```
mv-changes <source-commit> <destination-commit> <path>...
```

You can also run the script in Git-Bash shell on Windows.

Note that, if there are changes of `<path>` in intermediate commits between `source-commit` and `destination-commit`, it will not work.

Comment: It doesn't really works fully automatically as it pops up the editor but  it's great. Thanks..

Comment: It did a brilliant job on my end, no editor popping! Thanks!

Comment: Very helpful , Thanks!  (deserves much more than just a single plus)

Answer (score 5):

First take info on short history

```
> git log --oneline -n 3 --decorate=short
333333  (HEAD -> work_AAA) added test              /*file is updated here*/
222222  corrected bug 
111111  (origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) version XXX
```

so we can rebase and stop on commit 22222

```
> git rebase -i master 
pick 22222 corected bug 
pick 33333 added test
```

change to :

```
edit 22222 corected bug 
pick 33333 added test
```

then you will be in update mode in commit 22222 it shows something like this:

```
Stopped at 22222... corrected bug
You can amend the commit now, with
   git commit --amend 
Once you are satisfied with your changes, run
   git rebase --continue
```

here copy file from commit 3 to commit 2

```
git show 33333:path/to/file  >  path/to/file
```

amend commit 2 and continue rebase

```
git commit --amend --no-edit path/to/file
git rebase --continue
```

Done !

Comment: just to say I now use 'Mikhail Golubtsov' script :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and want to explain what I did.

In commit A I added a file f that I had to remove in the following commit B.

Now I wanted to get rid of the file in both commits but also wanted to avoid splitting the commit because there were many other files involved. I did this

- recover the file
- add it again in commit ADD
- remove it in commit REM - now there is the history A - B - ADD - REM
- squash commit A with REM - then the file vanishes out of A **and** B
- drop commit ADD - now the file is gone as it should be

Perhaps this is a quirky solution but for me it worked.
Please comment if you feel this is bad for some reasons.